# Can I only return data only if front-end webapp calls django app?

Tags: django, api, axios, rest

I have a Django app that "wraps" my Flickr API. The point of the wrapper is to hide the API key.

views.py:

```
...
def flickrApiGetPhotoSet(request):
    flickr_user_id = get_secret('flickr_user_id')
    flickr_photoset_id = get_secret('flickr_photoset_id')
    flickr_api_key = get_secret('flickr_api_key')
    response = requests.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?',
        params = {
            'method': 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
            'user_id': flickr_user_id,
            'photoset_id': flickr_photoset_id,
            'api_key': flickr_api_key,
            'format': 'json',
            'nojsoncallback': 1,
            'extras': 'date_upload'
        }
    )
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

While is Api-key is not exposed, the response is freely viewable in a browser.
e.g. mywebsite_domain.com/wrapper/flickrApiGetPhotoSet/

The 2 of the 3 pieces of data I was trying to hide (flickr_user_id, flickr_photoset_id) are exposed.

I have these values in my settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1','.mywebsite_domain.com','192.168.1.82']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
       'http://localhost',
       'https://www.mywebsite_domain.com',
)
```

On the front-end I'm using Axios to call the API: mywebsite_domain.com/wrapper/flickrApiGetPhotoSet/

Ideally, I'd like to only allow Axios to get the 'wrapped' response and get an error in the browser.

I'm not sure if there's something I need to update in (1) the Django API or (2) my 'wrapper' app or (3) something else.

Thanks in advance!
Larry

Comment: you get a response from this `response = requests.get('ht...` and it seems to be JSON so you could edit this JSON before you  `return HttpResponse(response...` and remove all the unwanted data. Like `response.pop('flickr_user_id', None)`

Comment: Thank you @hansTheFranz! This answer made me rethink how much data I was passing through to the FE, only passing what I needed. Additive vs subtractive approach. Best~

Comment: This solution works well for my case however I would like to explore alternatives as well. Perhaps I can clarify what I'm hoping to achieve using this example: 
At a previous company, we had private/internal APIs that provided data to the Front End. These endpoints were viewable with a simple browser - so long as I was connected to our internal network. However, when browsing from outside the network, the same request would result in a 403 error. I realize it's a bit apple-to-oranges. A corporate network vs a hosting company/3rd. Best~